# Need explanation of casting in Java. Which way is the best?

Tags: java, casting

I have the following code:

```
double d = 23d;
byte b = 52;

int result;
```

I am trying to store the result of `d + b` in `result` and I have to cast in order to do that, however I have found two ways to do that and I don't know what the difference is.

```
//First method
result = (int) d + b;

//Second Method
result = (int) (d+b);
```

What is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: You can add a `byte` to an `int` without a cast (a widening conversion), your first example converts `d` to an `int` and then adds `b` (which results in an `int`). Your second example adds `d` and `b` resulting in a `double` (which you then cast to an `int`).

Comment: no "best cast" in Your case. It DEPENDS  what behaviour You want.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, `d` is casted to `int`, and then added to `b`

```
result = (int) d + b;
// is also equivalent to
result = ((int) d) + b;
```

This is possible as adding a `byte` and a `double` can be done without any cast. On the other hand, `int result = (int) b + d` would fail, as this results in a `int` being added to a `double`, thus resulting in a `double`, that cannot be put in an int.

---

In the second case, the adding is done first, and then the result is casted to an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

First of methods casts only the first operand, which in this case is `d`. Second method casts the result of the sum of `d` and `b`.

Answer (score 3):

For most values, both expressions will return the same. However, take a look at this code that will illustrate the difference:

```
double d = 1 / (1 - (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)); // equal to 9.007199254740992E15
byte b = 1; 

System.out.println((long) d + b); // prints 9007199254740993
System.out.println((long) (d + b)); // prints 9007199254740992
```

**Now what happened ?**

- in the first expression, `d` is converted to an `long` first and then added to `b`
- in the second expression, `d + b` is calculated as a `double` value and then converted to a `long`

**Why does it matter ?**

I did not pick `d` randomly. This is a number for which `d + 1` is an integer but is impossible to represent as a `double` because it's a large number and `double` has limited precision. As a result, for this particular number `d + 1 == d` ! However, `long` has infinite precision for all integers that are small enough to fit in 64 bits. Therefore, converting `d` as a `long` before calculating `d + 1` gives us the real sum without precision error.

**PS:** I used `long` instead of `int` because this number would not fit in an `int` and woud overflow. The two expressions would still return two different results but it would make my point less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thxs! below explanation of my understandings may help you.

**1st Method Simplification:**
b is implicitly converted to double and added to d. then produce double value as a result and allocates a memory to store this double value first which is larger. Finally, casting to this value makes the result as int.

```
double d1 = d + b;
result = (int) d1;
```

**2nd Method Simplification:**
First b is implicitly converted to double and added to d then casting the resulting value into byte. As a result, it allocates a memory to store this byte value which is comparatively lower. Finally, this byte value is implicitly converted to int and produces the result as int.

```
byte b1 = (byte)(d + b);
result =  b1;
```

So we conclude that the **second method is the best one** because it allocates the lower memory spaces than the first method.

Comment: Memory space at this level is really negligible.